# Audio for Kivy app works on windows but not android

Tags: python, android, kivy, adb, buildozer

I have been trying to figure out this problem for days. I have two .wav files that I want to play when I press a button in my app.
When I run the program on my windows device the audio plays just fine. But when I compile my kivy app using buildozer into an .apk and run in it on my android device the audio doesn't play.
I did run a adb logcat on my app and this is the error it shows this:

```
[WARNING] [AudioSDL2   ] Unable to load /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/137523215.wav: b'java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/timidity/freepats.cfg'`.
```

I also included the wav files in my bulldozer spec file.

```
# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,ttf,wav
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you play back any media file using your kivy on Android or is it a problem with those two WAV files?

Comment: It doesn't matter what type of audio file I use. None of them playback on android.

Comment: The Android environment may base on Linux but a lot details are different. I remember that on https://android.stackexchange.com there are a few questions on playing audio "the Linux way". May be those questions help you to understand why it is not working.

Comment: Did you check the file path(s) ?

Comment: All the files I used for my app are all in the same directory and at the same level.